# Trying to install wordpress in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed on domain.com 
Now I'm trying to install another wordpress on domain.com/sweets/ 
I uploaded everything but once I get to the "sweets/wp-admin/setup-config.php" path 
it shows a page in domain.com saying "Not Found"

I assume it has something to do with the .htaccess?

**.htaccess of domain.com/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You are trying `/sweets/wp-admin/setup-config.php`, yes?

Comment: It may help if you posted your current .htaccess

Comment: This is not a htaccess issue. Htaccess doesn't come into play before WP is installed

Comment: Is this a fresh wordpress setup? Are you 1000% sure the file really exists?

Comment: Does the file exist?  And are the permissions on it such that the installer can open it?

Comment: Ok that's just odd, file permissions of wp-admin/ folder were 444,  set it to 755 and it works... kind of weird that it redirects to the parent folder's website though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments thread as it appears to have solved the problem:

Does the file exist? And are the permissions on it such that the installer can open it?

Answer from Asaf: 
Ok that's just odd, file permissions of wp-admin/ folder were 444, set it to 755 and it works... kind of weird that it redirects to the parent folder's website though